# Laravel - Read file from workbench/vendor package

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am developing a package for laravel4 and I need to read in a csv file.  I have been unable to find a way to get the path to the file.

I've tried doing things like:

`$file = File::get('data/myfile.csv');`

It appears however, that this is relative to the root path of the laravel app and not the package.

I could use `app_path()` and manually add the workbench/vendor folder on, but that's not ideal.  I also don't want the file to "published" to the main app, it needs to remain in the package folder.

In my ServiceProvider it seems I can use `$this->guessPackagePath()` which gives me the path but this doesn't work for a controller.

How can I get the path for the package in order to read in this file?

Comment: I have zero experience developing packages but what if you created a custom config value that specifies where your package i located in relation to say `app_path`? Publish it & then you could call the custom config like `Config::get('package.value')`. Like I said, I could be way off here, but this would at least enable you to get the package path from anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to automatically determine this.  If a package is installed via composer it should not require the user to add the path into the config file.  I'm sure there must be a way to determine the path, I just cant find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution that works, while not exactly what I would have liked, it serves it's purpose.

So this is the folder structure I have:

```
workbench
    - vendorname
      - appname
        - src
            - controllers
                - mycontroller.php
            - data
                - myfile.csv
```

In mycontroller.php I can access the csv file like follows:

```
$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/data/';
$contents = File::get($path . 'myfile.csv');
```

The `dirname` is used twice in order to get the parent folder.

By using `__FILE__` it keeps the path relative to wherever the script is.  This means whether I'm working on it in workbench or whether it's published to the vendor folder or if any parent folders are renamed - the path to the csv file will still work.

Comment: `__DIR__` will give you the directory name, saving you one call to `dirname`.

Comment: You could have just done `__DIR__ . '/../data/myfile.csv';`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a routine I came across in a Testbench TestCase class:

```
protected function getPackagePath()
{
    return realpath( implode( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, [
        __DIR__,
        '..',
        'src',
        'MyPackage'
    ] ) );
}
```